# Downloading data from yahoo finance using fimport package in R

Tags: r, quantmod, yahoo-finance

I know that there is already questions about Yahoo finance failures. However, I tried to download data using the `fimport` package using the following code:

```
sp500 <- yahooSeries("SPY", from = "2006-01-01", to = "2017-05-12")
```

with error

> 'HTTP status was '504 Maximum Transaction Time Exceeded'

Does anybody know if the packages (`fimport`, `quantmod`, etc.) dealing with downloading data from Yahoo finance will be updated soon? Does anybody have a simple way to fix it?

Comment: Please share with us your attempts and the link you desire to get the data from.

Comment: trying:                                                                                                   
   sp500 <- yahooSeries("SPY",from = "2006-01-01",to = "2017-05-12")

Comment: Please add all the modifications in the initial question. Also don't forget the packages you are using

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. First I uninstalled `quantmod` und reinstalled by

```
devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod", ref="157_yahoo_502")
```

with the help of package `devtools`. After that I was able to use `getSymbols` function:

```
library(quantmod)
start <- as.Date("2007-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2017-05-18")
getSymbols("SPY", src = "yahoo", from =start, to = end)
```

Comment: Hi! it's working, thanks!